# How to show two Frames side by side in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

[This is what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mth2g.png)

[This is what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTHcx.png)

I've tried it like 2 hours with reading the documentation and every tutorial I could possibly find but after all I'm not able to display two `ttk.Frames` side by side with a border around them.
What have I done wrong?

This is my code so far (and yeah, I know, I've never used `self.path` but I just like to have it available in need):

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

class GUI(ThemedTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_theme("breeze")
        self.path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.title("Kniffel All In One")
        self.defineVariables()

        # Root Window
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=5)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.LeftFrame = ttk.Frame(self, border=True, borderwidth=1)
        self.LeftFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="NSWE")
        self.RightFrame= ttk.Frame(self, border=True, borderwidth=1)
        self.RightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="NSWE")

        # LeftFrame
        self.LeftEntry = ttk.Entry(self.LeftFrame, textvariable=self.text1).grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky="WE")
        self.LeftLabel  = ttk.Label(self.LeftFrame, text="Little test left side").grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky="WE")

        # RightFrame
        self.RightEntry = ttk.Entry(self.RightFrame, textvariable=self.text2).grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky="WE")
        self.RightLabel = ttk.Label(self.RightFrame, text="Litte test right side").grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky="WE")

        self.mainloop()

    def defineVariables(self):
        self.text1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.text2 = tk.StringVar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI()
```

Note that I didn't use `.pack()` and `.grid()` together and it doesn't display a border even though I thought `border=True` would show one.

Please be so kind to just answer my question since I haven't ask for aesthetics, readability or programming style improvements. Also this won't be a professional application.
Thanks for understanding this.

Comment: `self.LeftFrame` and `self.RightFrame` are both None, the result of the `.grid()` calls rather than the actual Frames.  When you pass None as the `parent` parameter for the other widgets you create, you are telling them to be a child of the root window instead.  You need to do the geometry management as a separate statement.

Comment: Ah damn, never thought of that, give me a second, I'll try out removing the .grid(...) and separate it out

Comment: I've updated the question to match your suggested code.

Now I have two Frames next to each other, but without the border, also the `self.columnconfigure(0, weight=5)`
`self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)`
is ignored for some reason

Comment: I think you just need to add a `relief=` option to make the borders visible - the default appears to be 'flat', which produces no visible effect.  The `weight=` options specify how *excess space* is distributed between the columns - but there is no excess space, the default behavior is for everything to shrink down to the minimum size needed to hold its contents.

Comment: Yeah you helped a lot, thank you very much!